# Managed DLL referenced by 2 Winform apps. Winform 1 launches Winform 2, but context is shared unless both are executed separately

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c++-cli, winforms-interop

I have two WinForm client applications that reference the same managed DLL (written in C++/CLI) with the purpose of connecting to a native socket server.

Both Winform applications run fine when launched separately, but not when one launches the other.

Let's say that client Winform 1 is launched. It creates its own socket and context as intended and then proceeds to launch Winform 2 as a separate thread.

Winform 2 will also open its own socket as a client of the native server, but when Winform 2 closes its socket and exits, Winform 1 stops working because it seems to think it's Winform 2. So any server requests by WinForm 1 fail because its socket becomes the one previously closed by socket 2.

This behavior is new to me, but it must obviously extend beyond variable "SOCKET socket_id".

Is Winform 2 supposed to be launched as a separate process instead of the typical thread that executes Application.Run(Winform2)?

Thanks.

```
private void LaunchWinForm2Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     System.Threading.Thread myThread = 
         new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(StartWinForm2));

     myThread.Start(); 
}

private void StartWinForm2()
{
        CSharpFormApp.WinForm2 theWinForm2 = new CSharpFormApp.WinForm2();
        Application.Run(theWinForm2);

}
```

Comment: Can you provide some code that shows how you are actually launching WinForm2?

Comment: Hey Mike. WinForm 2 launches fine and does everything it needs to do. I have added the code that does this.

Comment: The problem seems to be in the c++ library. Do you have any globals or statics there? Seems like something is declared at process scope

Comment: How do you manage your client sockets exactly?

Comment: Thanks Oguz Ozgul. Your comment served as key insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with a global pointer to native data in the C++/CLI DLL. 
Since the WinForms get their data through several C++/CLI interfaces, it was initially easier to just have them access native data through a global pointer.

```
NativeLayer::NativeLayerData* native_data;


public ref class Test1Implementer : ITest1
{
     virtual bool TestConnect()
     {
        bool success = native_data->Connect();
        return success;
     }
};

public ref class Test2Implementer : ITest2
{
     virtual bool TestDisconnect()
     {
        bool success = native_data->Disconnect();
        return success;
     }
};
```

Eventually, such an implementation would come back to haunt me, but those are the perils of attempting to use globals in industrial applications.

Once I got rid of the managed global pointer to native data, everything works as intended. Here's a possible solution that allows for multithreading using nested interfaces:

```
public ref class TestsImplementer : ITests 
{
private:
    NativeLayer::NativeLayerData* native_data;

public:
      TestsImplementer()
      {
         native_data = new NativeLayer::NativeLayerData();
      }

      ref class Test1Implementer : ITest1
      {
         virtual bool TestConnect(TestsImplementer^ tests)
         {
            bool success = tests->native_data->Connect();
            return success;
         }
      };

      ref class Test2Implementer : ITest2
      {
         virtual bool TestDisconnect(TestsImplementer^ tests)
         {
            bool success = tests->native_data->Disconnect();
            return success;
         }
      };
};
```